# Infer object property type from within method parameter

Tags: typescript

Given `IColumn` interface where `data` param value equals `T[dataKey]`:

```js
interface IColumn<T> {
    dataKey: keyof T;
    process?(data, record: T, index: number): any;
}
```

How to infer type of `data` in `IColumn` implementations ?

```js
interface IImg {
    img: string;
}

const columns: IColumn<IImg>[] = [{
    dataKey: "img",
    process(data) { // data is of type any
      return data.replace('something', 'something else')
    }
}]
```

See more details in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infer-1y36x)

Answer (score 1):

By rights either `IColumn` needs to be generic both in `T` and the particular key `K extends keyof T` for the `dataKey` property, *or* it needs to be a [union](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of all such values corresponding to each `K in keyof T`.  Without more information about your use case I'd lean toward the union type so you don't have to carry around an extra generic type parameter.

Here is what it looks like:

```
type IColumn<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    dataKey: K;
    process?(data: T[K], record: T, index: number): any
  }
}[keyof T];
```

And it works the way you want:

```
const columns: IColumn<IImg>[] = [{
  dataKey: "img",
  process(data) { // data is of type string
    return data.replace('something', 'something else')
  }
}]
```

---

Otherwise, the generic interface would work something like this:

```
interface IColumn<T, K extends keyof T> {
  dataKey: K;
  process?(data: T[K], record: T, index: number): any
}

const asColumn = <T>() => <K extends keyof T>(column: IColumn<T, K>) => column;
const asIImgColumn = asColumn<IImg>();
const columns = [asIImgColumn({
  dataKey: "img",
  process(data) { // data is of type string
    return data.replace('something', 'something else')
  }
})];
```

where a helper function or something like it is needed to infer the particular value of `K` you need for each `IColumn<T, K>` instance, or you need to specify manually.  You can see how the union type is more straightforward when you just want to say "some `K`" instead of "a particular `K`".

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-XyYwHAjZgiAQqHohHI76opC7zH7hq4-GE4k5RLKYqZIA)

Comment: First works great and looks cleaner than using helpers. 
By the way, I'm not sure what you mean about "some K" instead of "a particular K".

Comment: By "some `K`" I mean "I want `K` to be *some* key of `T` but I don't care which one and I'm not going to ask about which one it is, later", whereas by "a particular `K`" I mean "I want `K` to be *this particular* key of `T`, and I will need to refer back to it later, so don't forget which one it is".   Concretely, it's the difference between the type of `columns` being `Array<IColumn<IImg>>` (an array of valid `IColumn<IImg>` whose particular `dataKey` is irrelevant to me now) vs `[IColumn<IImg, "img">]` (an array with a single `IColumn<IImg>` whose `dataKey` is `"img"`).

Comment: That what I understood... but the fact is that with both styles above, `render(data)` implementations gives me the particular `K`

Comment: `render()`?  Not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: My bad, I mean `process(data)`